# passing data to function and using it node.js sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have this:

```
function afterCreateThePayment(req, res, rows) {

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    
    console.log(rows.length)
    var selecter = "SELECT * from SCHEDULE WHERE CLIENT_USERNAME = ? AND SESSION_STATUS = ?"
    //pass rows into this function
    mysqlconn.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
            return;
          }
    
        mysqlconn.query(selecter, [rows[i]["USERNAME"], 'CONFIRMED'], async function(err, scheduleData) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            

            for (var x = 0; x < scheduleData.length; x++) {
                console.log(scheduleData[x])
            }
            
            // mysqlconn.end();
        })
       
    })
   
}
}
```

as you can see, i am passing `rows` into this function, and then trying to use `rows[i]["USERNAME"]` as one of the query parameters. However, when I do this, I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'USERNAME' of undefined
```

so i am not sure what to do here, or if my logic is correct. could someone help?

Comment: Could you do a console.log(rows) on the second line of the function? what do you get there?

Comment: @JohnniO. it returns everything I need it to, all of the data within the table

Comment: And what do you get when you write console.log(rows[i]) just after the beginng of the loop? Is there a property called USERNAME? Maybe this property is in a array within rows[i]?

Comment: @JohnniO. it returns all the values I want it to again. `username` does exist, it is returned data from my database table. I think the problem is that when i use `rows[i]["USERNAME"]` within the technically new function that is being defined here `mysqlconn.connect(function(err) {`. but if i pass rows through, it still gives me the same error. so that is what is confusing to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that he loop variable `i` is scoped to `afterCreateThePayment`. Keep in mind that `var` in javascript uses functional scoping, which is different than the block scoping you may be familiar with in C-style languages.

I am assuming that the callback from `mysqlconn.connect` is asynchronous. This means that the loop continues to execute, incrementing `i`. By the time the callback happens, the loop is out of bounds. If you peek at the value of `i` (not `rows`) in your callback you'll see what has happened.

Here is a similar example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  function internal()
  {
    console.log(i);
  }
  setTimeout(() => {internal();},1000);
}
```

The simplest option is swapping out the `var i` in your loop for `let i`. Making this change will make the `i` block scoped, so that the value will apply just to your current call to `mysqlconn.connect`. In my example, that's simply:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  function internal()
  {
    console.log(i);
  }
  setTimeout(() => {internal();},1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! So are you basically saying to replace the `var i` with `let i`, but then also put `setTimeout(() => {internal();},5);` (but edited for my code) in there as well?

Comment: No to the `setTimeout` portion -- that was simply there to make my example asynchronous without the external call. All you should need to do in your case is swap the `var i` to `let i`

Comment: ohh i see what you're saying. that worked like a charm. thank you so much! you're explanation helped a lot